# How to merge first part of a list value prior to a character, based on the values after the character in python

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I need to combine the element values of a list in python. This is based on the values coming after a specific character in the element. For example:
I have a below input list value

```
[('245|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE'), ('129|AREA-VARCHAR'),('450|DIVISION-VARCHAR'),('678|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE'),('298|DIVISION-VARCHAR')]
```

I have to get the output list as below

```
[('245,678|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE'), ('129|AREA-VARCHAR'),('450,298|DIVISION-VARCHAR')]
```

So in the list, if the values of two elements after the pipe(|) is same, I have to club the values before pipe(|) as comma separated values.

The clubbing should occur into the element which is placed first out of the two.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [('245|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE'), ('129|AREA-VARCHAR'),('450|DIVISION-VARCHAR'),('678|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE'),('298|DIVISION-VARCHAR')]
print([','.join([x.split('|')[0] for x in v]) + '|' + i for i, v in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.split('|')[1]), lambda x: x.split('|')[1])])
```

Output:

```
['129|AREA-VARCHAR', '245,678|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE', '450,298|DIVISION-VARCHAR']
```

Answer (score 0):

First you may keep the numbers related to a string together, use a dict for this : key is the string, value a list if the ints

```
occurences = {}
for value in values:
    content = value.split("|")
    occurences[content[1]] = occurences.get(content[1], []) + [content[0]]

print(occurences)  # {'CALENDAR_DATE-DATE': ['245', '678'], 'AREA-VARCHAR': ['129'], 
                   #  'DIVISION-VARCHAR': ['450', '298']}
```

Then just concat each pairs using your formatting

```
result = [','.join(v) + '|' + k for k, v in occurences.items()]

print(result) # ['245,678|CALENDAR_DATE-DATE','129|AREA-VARCHAR','450,298|DIVISION-VARCHAR']
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer I’m missing something ?

Comment: You lectured the OP about how this isn't  `a site where you post a problem and get some code in return`, then you turn around a post code disproving your original claim.